# how to correctly make an iframe src equal whatever my variable equals?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm trying to make it so that whatever my variable, named "cover", equals in my html body, the iframe will use that as a source. I have it setup like this in my js file:

```
var cover = elem.attr('myFrame');

var cover = document.getElementById("myFrame"); 

$('.player .cover').attr('src','http://fakeurl.com/' + cover+'');
```

and then i have this in a part of the html body:

```
    <iframe class="cover" id="myFrame"></iframe>


<ul id="audioplayer" class="playlist visible">

    <li audiourl="1.mp3" cover="fakeurl1" artist="pinkzebra" album="AudioJungle">In the Moment of Inspiration</li>

    <li audiourl="2.mp3" cover="fakeurl2.html" artist="pinkzebra" album="AudioJungle">Inspiring Ideas into Motion</li>

    <li audiourl="3.mp3" cover="fakeurl3.html" artist="pinkzebra" album="AudioJungle">Peaceful Dawn</li>

    <li audiourl="1.mp3" cover="fakeurl4.html" artist="pinkzebra" album="AudioJungle">Photos and Memories</li>
    <li audiourl="2.mp3" cover="fakeurl5.html" artist="pinkzebra" album="AudioJungle">Soaring Spirit</li>

</ul><!-- /.playlist -->
```

The iframe shows the correct url (e.g. fakeurl.com) , but instead of adding what cover equals to the URL, it just enters in [object HTMLIFrameElement]
any ideas how to make it say (in example, http://fakeurl.com/fakeurl1.html).
this is a music playlist so im trying to make it so whenever a certain audio is plaing, the iframe will equal whatever cover= for that song

Comment: I couldn't understand what you are doing in the first two lines in your code. What is `elem`? And why are you declaring `cover` twice?

Comment: why can you just set like `document.getElementById('myFrame').src = 'your url'`

Comment: this is a music playlist so im trying to make it so whenever a certain audio is plaing, the iframe will equal whatever cover= for that song

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using `getElementById` when you have jQuery?

```
var cover = $('#cover');
```

You're also declaring `cover` twice and I can't see an HTML element with the `.player` class, nor with a `myFrame` attribute. Your code essentially sets the string representation of the iframe reference as its own src attribute.

That aside, I think what you want to do is something like this:

```
$(function(){
    // When a playlist item is chosen
    $('#audioplayer li').click(function(){
        // Set the iframe src attribute to fakeurl.com 
        // with the playlist item's cover attribute appended
        $('#myFrame').attr('src','http://fakeurl.com/'+$(this).attr('cover'));
    });
});
```

Check out this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/3LGW8/

Comment: this worked however since this is a music player, it only works when you click on the song to play, not necessarily when the song is "selected" but thats a whole other story thats probably more complicated, ill try figuring out how to make it use the cover variable when the song is actually playing, ill just have to do some digging through the audio player javascript file. THANKS A BUNCH

Answer (score 0):

The way you do the concatenation is wrong here

```
.attr('src','http://fakeurl.com/' + cover+'');
```

Rather do like this (this is just based on your approach. I'm not sure why you have two `cover` var declared

```
var url = 'http://fakeurl.com/' + cover
$('.player .cover').attr('src',url);
```

or more eleganty I would directly set like this

```
document.getElementById('myFrame').src = 'fixed url' + cover
```

Comment: well I did this now: var url2 = 'http://fakeurl.com/' + cover var cover = elem.attr('myFrame');
     and now the iframe takes me to http://fakeurl.com/undefined instead of what cover equals

Comment: why there is is a `;` for `var url2 = 'fakeurl.com/'; + cover` before concatenating with `cover` value? can you `alert(cover);` and see what comes through?

Comment: thanks for your time man! i alerted cover and the window pops up empty, no url text or anything

Comment: then it's obvious that your `cover` variable which holds the part of the url is empty. Trying to concatenate with other values will result in nothing. how do you get value for variable `cover`? from your code `var cover = document.getElementById("myFrame");` it just holds a reference to a control.